# Apple pay using Stripe shows error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, flutter-dependencies, applepay

Apple pay using stripe shows an error in flutter before it's working fine but currently shows an error. Payment intent generating working fine but when I do payment it shows this error.

[image]

Comment: Contact Stripe support, they are quite good. We cannot really tell what an "unexpected error" is. You did upgrade your package to the latest version, right?

Comment: @nvoigt Thanks for respond, before apple pay worked fine but its shows error when i change stripe account

Comment: Well, we cannot help you here. If you are running the latest version and it's an "unexpected error", then you will need to contact their support. *They* can trace what went wrong, we cannot.